# Insert an Image in a Google Document

Tags: image, insert, google-docs-api, insert-image

I create this script to insert a simple picture into a simple Google Document:

```
function myInsertImage() {
  var MyImage = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6we#/media/File:Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg";

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  doc.getBody().insertImage(0, MyImage);
}
```

I get always get this error:

> "Method insertImage(number, string) not found"

When I changed `insertImage` to `appendImage`, it has the same problem.

Does anyone know where is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this using Google Apps Script:

```
function myInsertImage() {
  var fileId = "123456789";
  var myImage = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob(); 

               or 

                DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getAs('img/png');

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  doc.getBody().insertImage(0, myImage);
}
```

or

```
function myInsertImage() {
    var url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6we#/media/File:Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg";
    var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().insertImage(0, img.getBlob());

}
```

This will insert an image at the top of the document.

For more infos:

- [`insertImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertimagechildindex-image)
- [`fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Hello, many thanks for this beautiful master script. Exact what I need :). One thing I have found out: the picture must be in a ".png"-Format - ".jpg" will not run.

Comment: Sure thing. If this works fine, kindly accept my answer :)